# Got stuck trying to do the integration of $ \int \frac{\ e^x (\cos x - \sin x)}{\sin^2 x} dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$\int \frac{\ e^x (\cos x - \sin x)}{\sin^2 x} dx$

Tried to do multiply and got $ \int \left(\frac{\ e^x \cos x}{\sin^2 x} \right)$ - $ \int \left(\frac{\ e^x}{\sin x}\right)$, but still stuck on that.

Could you help me, please?

Comment: What is the derivative of $\frac{e^x \cos x}{\sin x}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply integration by parts (differentiating $e^x$ and integrating $\csc x\cot x$),
\begin{align}
\int e^x\csc x\cot xdx-\int e^x\csc xdx&=\left[e^x(-\csc x)-\int e^x(-\csc x)dx\right]-\int e^x\csc xdx+C\\
&=-e^x\csc x+C
\end{align}
where $C$ is the constant of integration.

Answer (score 2):

The integrand looks very much like a derivative that we could get via the quotient rule. Recall that the quotient rule states:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{f'(x)g(x)-f(x)g'(x)}{[f(x)]^2}$$
After a bit of thought we may be able to see that the numerator is equal to
$$e^x(\frac{d}{dx}\sin(x)-\sin x)=-(\sin x\frac{d}{dx}e^x-e^x\frac{d}{dx}\sin(x))$$ and so our integral is equal to
$$-\frac{e^x}{\sin x}+C$$

---

I hope that helps. If you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask. Much of the credit for this answer goes to Alann Rosas as a result of his recent answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4099830/what-other-tricks-and-techniques-can-i-use-in-integration)
.