# How do I prove $\int_0^\pi tf(\sin t) dt = 1/2 \int_0^\pi f(\sin t) dt$?

Tags: integration, functions, trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

I am not really sure how to approach this. I have tried to use integration by parts but it does not seem to work.

Thank you

Comment: First off, we can get rid of the $i$ factor from both sides, since $i\ne 0$, this is an equivalent transformation.

Comment: This seems to not hold, at least not for any $f$. If $f$ is simply the identity, then the left side is $i(\sin(p)-p\cos(p))$, and the right side is $\frac{i}{2}\left(1-\cos(p)\right)$, which are different functions. (For one, the left side results in an even function, the right side results in an odd function.)

Comment: I think you mean to have $\pi$ as the upper limit on both integrals, with the factor $\pi$ in the right-hand side. This is a well-known identity which is easily proved by substituting $u=\pi-t$

Comment: @DavidQuinn yes that's what I meant - I am sorry for the typo - I am not very familiar with how to get the pi symbol. So while substituting, do you have to split the integral and then prove?

Comment: @DanieP - I just realised that there was a typo here - i meant for the upper limit to equal pi - I am very new to the platform so I was unsure how to get the pi symbol - sorry for that

Comment: type \pi with to get $\pi$. No just substitute $u=\pi-t$

Comment: @akr22 $\sin(t)$ won't change under this substitution.

Comment: @DavidQuinn Thank you, so regarding the substitution do you then rearrange for t and then replaced the t with pi - u to get the integral (pi to 0) [ (pi - u)f(sin(u))] = 1/2 integral (pi to 0) f(sinu)] ?

Comment: @Jakobian - it would just be sin(u) right which is just sin(t)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let $A=\pi^2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{1 + \sin(\pi x)}dx$ and $B=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{x\sin( x)}{1 + \sin( x)}dx$. Find $\frac{A}{B}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4316372/let-a-pi2-int-01-frac-sin-pi-x1-sin-pi-xdx-and-b-int-0)

Comment: @RobertLee Not really because I am not sure how to integrate the tf(sint) bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From left side

$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi}xf(\sin x)dx$$

$$=\int_{0}^{\pi}(\pi-x)f(\sin x)dx$$

hence $$\color{red}I=
\frac{\pi}{2} \color{blue}\int_{0}^{\pi}f(\sin x)dx$$