# Methods of mathematical proof's

Tags: proof-explanation

I have a curiosity about mathematical proofs and I don't know how to research it properly. I apologize to the admins in advance, but it's a genuine question.

Given a proposition P, are there other demonstration methods that allow me to prove that P is true, other than the usual/classic ones (direct proof, contradiction, contraposition and induction)?

Comment: Some others are listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_proof#Methods_of_proof). For some types of proposition, we can go further. For example, there are [many ways](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4099830) to prove "this integral has this value".

Comment: There are a few books on this topic. I have heard "How to Prove it" by Velleman is good.

Comment: In a sense, there is only one way to prove anything: the direct proof: a list of statements that are either axioms, or a statement $A$ which is preceeded in the list by statements $B$ and $B \implies A$. All other methods of proof are essentially metamathematical demonstrations that a direct proof exists.